# Grails 2.0.X Auto Reloading

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, grails-2.0

I have grails 2.0.4 installed with STS 2.9.2, I am facing an issue that Auto Reloading of controllers is not happening.

I have tried below methods

1) grails clean

2) Deleted the project under %user_home%/.grails/projects/%

3) crated a new project

Is there any workaround for this

Comment: Happens to me too sometimes from grails versions 2.0 + . Seems to be bug. :-)

Comment: I'm using grails 2.0.4 with Windows 7 Pro x64 and the reaload works fine. Did you use ctrl + F5 to reload the page?

Comment: I have got 32 bit machine, with ctrl+F5, only CSS files can be auto reloaded not Controllers.

Comment: Any solutions to this!? Seeing the same thing here...

Comment: What command are you using to run the app is RunApp Or run-app